# Trying to add and image to view order page magento 2

Tags: php, magento2

I'm trying to add a thumbnali image to the view order page in the account section with the following code but it doesn't do anything:

```
<td>
    <?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId()); ?>
    <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="" />
</td>
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: have you confirm this $_item->getId() .it has some id or not

Comment: getId() appears to be the order number and not the product how would i get the product?

Comment: then how will get the product pic from order id lol

Comment: How would you generally call an image?

Answer (score 0):

Try the codes given below:

First load the product

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());
```

Then show the thumbnail where you want using the code given below

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(75, 75); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()); ?>" border="0" width="75" />
```

Comment: I get: Class 'Mage' not found in